# Spring java code form post and redirection to a different server

Tags: java, spring, http, post

I am building a web application using Spring framework that requires users to make a payment. When the user posts a form, it redirects to Hp's payment website and processes the payments there before returning to my application. This method however leaves my applications vulnerable to security threats and form manipulations.

I now want to post the form to my server, validate users inputs and if necessary post data to hp's web server. I have already written a java code for posting a form from my code and getting the response back into a file from hp's site but am unable to figure out how to redirect the user to the hp website using the java form post. Can someone please help? I am new to Spring so am open to suggestions that would help me accomplish this task either using this method or another way to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you need to perform the redirect on the server side, not on the client side. Redirection is basically returning HTTP 302 with `Location` header pointing to new location. When browser receives such response it opens the URL in question rather than rendering the response like it is with 200.

If you can receive and validate your form all you have to do is send the redirect back to the browser. I don't know which web framework do you use. In [servlets](/questions/tagged/servlets) you simply say:

```
response.sendRedirect("http://www.example.com/payment/...");
```

In [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) return the following string from your controller as opposed to a view name:

```
return "redirect:http://www.example.com/payment/...";
```